# KDE: Virtual desktops: how to make each desktop grid square shortcut have its own color

Tags: kubuntu, kde, virtualdesktop

I have these virtual desktops on Kubuntu 20.04:

[image]

To easier distinguish between them, I'd like each to have its own color, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve?